# A reliable way to read socket data

Tags: java, android, tcp

The application that I am working on has two parts. The server part runs on a Linux machine. The client part, an Android application, queries the server and gets necessary response. Both the parts are written in Java, use socket-based communication, and transfer textual data.

Right after sending the request, here is how the client receives the response:

```
public static String ReadAvailableTextFromSocket(BufferedReader input) throws IOException {
  if (input.ready() == false) {
    return null;
  }
  StringBuilder retVal = new StringBuilder();
  while(input.ready()) {
    char ch = (char) input.read();
    retVal.append(ch);
  }
  return retVal.toString();
}
```

However, this doesn't seem to be that reliable. The input is not always ready because of server response time or transmission delays.

Looks like input.ready() is not the right way to wait for getting data.

I am wondering if there is a better way to accomplish this. Perhaps there is some standard practice that I could use.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should use [Threads](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/). Keep a listener thread in a `while(true)` loop that reads more data as it comes in, and simply buffers the data in a data structure (let's say a queue) shared with the main thread. That way, the main thread could simply dequeue data as needed. If the queue is empty, it can infer that no new data was received.

Edit: see this [multithreaded chat server/client](http://www.ase.md/~aursu/ClientServerThreads.html) code as an example.

Comment: Thank you for your help. The data is currently being received in a background thread. However, I think the problem still does not go away. Some thread, either background or foreground, would have to wait for certain time and then decide that the data is not going to come. I think I just may have to introduce the notion of how-long-to-wait-for-data.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I solved this problem. As I am responsible for writing both, the client side as well as the server side, when a request comes to the server, the first line of information I send as the response is the number of bytes the client can expect. This way, the client first waits to read a line. Once the line is read, the client now knows how many bytes of data to expect from the server.

Hope this helps others.

Regards,
Peter